# Change image on .slideToggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `p` tag that when it's clicked some text show up using `.slideToggle`, but the one thing I can't get to work, is that when you click the `p` tag, the arrow next to it will change from pointing right, to pointing down. And when you click on the p tag again it will go back to pointing right instead of pointing down.

html:

```
<p id="section1">&#9658; Consectetur</p> 
<table class="bordered"> 
<tr> 
<td class="blue_box_outer_left">Lorem</td> 
<td class="white_box">Ipsum</td> 
<td class="white_box">Sit</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<p id="section1_balk">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p> 

<p id="section2">&#9658; Adipiscing</p> 
<table class="bordered"> 
<tr> 
<td class="white_box">Nam</td> 
<td class="blue_box">Vitae</td> 
<td class="blue_box">Enim</td> 
<td class="white_box">Quam</td> 
</tr> 
</table> 
<p id="section2_balk">Nam vitae enim eget quam vestibulum posuere. Phasellus id.</p>
```

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 2 ; i++) { 
$('#section'+i).click( function() { 
    $('#'+this.id+'_balk').slideToggle(); 
            }); 
    }  
});
```

You can see the whole thing here:

http://jsfiddle.net/hbrovell/65dbG/

And the arrow entities will be replaced with an image of an arrow.

Anyone got a solution on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

See in action: http://jsfiddle.net/y5LAJ/22/

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
for(var i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++) { 
  $('#section'+i).click( function() {
    var me = $(this);
      $('#'+this.id+'_balk').slideToggle(
        function () {
          if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
            me.addClass('open');
          }
          else {
            me.removeClass('open'); 
          }
        }) 
      }); 
    }  
});
```

You can also try icon webfonts for the icons.

```
p[id^="section"].toggle-section:before {
    content: "\25B6";
    padding-right: 5px;
}
p[id^="section"].toggle-section.open:before {
    content: "\25BC";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could have grouped the HTML better like making different accordions to different DIVs so that handling could be easier. Since I don't want to change your HTML extensively, I made a script to make the existing to work. Please see the updated Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/65dbG/2/)

I had to apply some bad approach in DOM traversal because of the bad structure in HTML like the one below.

```
$(this).prev().prev().find('img').attr('src',downImage);
```

Comment: When I first started develop this, I used divs instead of tables but didn't get the result I wanted. If you have time it would be interesting to see how you would have grouped the HTML @Ananthan